# Get Set values of TextBox Control from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

Let say I have this code on Page load of ASP.NET Webform

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "123";
}
```

and this is my control in aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

If I change the textbox data from 123 to 12548 or any thing in the front end and then I click the button
Now in this is my code behind button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Now in `TextBox1.Text` I should be getting 12548 or updated value instead I am getting 123 which I have already set in page load.

Now I want to get the updated value, how may I do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a NOT is Postback

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      TextBox1.Text = "123";
    }
}
```

or remove it completely:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //not here
}

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="123" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Page_Load as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "123";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this "In ASP.Net every time you cause a postback of any kind, including handling events like button clicks, you're working with a brand new instance of your page class that must be rebuilt from scratch. Any work you've done previously to build the page on the server is gone. That means running the entire page life cycle, including your page load code, and not just the click code.

Every time you perform any event in the front end it will recreate the page and call the pageload method again and the page would be actually reset. To avoid it one should use the following code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostback)
        {
             //default code
        }
    }
```